# Ecliipseで改行時にタブが入るようにしたい

Tags: eclipse

現在JavaをEclipseで実装しています。

インデントの設定に関することなのですが、
**改行時にタブでインデントされるようにしたい**です。
色んなサイトを参考にして試してみてもどうしてもスペース４つが入ってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

チームの他の方は問題なく、タブで改行されているのに私の環境だけがスペースで改行されてしまいます。
**if文などのブロックを改行したときにタブで改行するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？**

以下私の設定です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

追記
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 問題を切り分けることも兼ねて、うまく動作する人のコードフォーマッターのプロファイルをエクスポートしてもらって、それをインポートしてみるのは、どうでしょう？

Comment: それも思ったのですが、既存のフォーマッター「Eclipseビルトイン」を他の方は利用しており、私もそれを利用していたのですが、違いが出てしまいました。そのため何が原因なのかわかっていないのですが、他の人と設定が違うなりに改行のスペース４つで処理されるところを治そうとしていました。他の設定もある程度見比べていただいたのですが、変なところはなさそうとのことでした。

Comment: であれば、Eclipseのバグの可能性もありそうですね。使っているEclipseのバージョンに違いはありませんか？

Comment: 配布元が同じはずなのでバージョンも同じはずですが一応確認してみます

Comment: プロジェクトの固有の設定で「Javaコード・スタイル」「フォーマッター」のアクティブなプロファイルが変更されていることはないでしょうか？

Comment: アクティブなプロファイルは今は意図的に変えています。というのも元々のeclipseビルトインのままにしていたのに、改行の際にスペース4つが入力される(他の方と挙動が違う)ため、フォーマッターを編集するために新たに作ったからです。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
プロジェクト→プロパティ→Java→フォーマッター

の設定で「プロジェクト固有の設定を可能にする」にチェックが入っており、そのフォーマッターのタブポリシーが混合になっておりました。

その「プロジェクト固有の設定を可能にする」のチェックを外すと、ウインドウ→設定から設定したフォーマッターが機能し、解決されました。

ご協力いただいた方ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

(私のキャプチャは日本語化していないものなので、適宜読み替えてください)

該当する設定は、 Preferencesの **Java > Editor > Typing** にある **Indentation** という設定です。下のキャプチャでは(塗りつぶしてしまってわかりづらいですが) "*using spaces*"という説明がある通り、スペースでインデントする設定になっています。

[image: Java > Editor > Typing]

これをtabに変更するには、説明文にある通り、**Formatter**設定でインデントがtabになっているのが前提になります。

**Java > Code Style > Formatter** の **Edit** ボタンで編集画面に行き、 **Indentation > Tab policy** の設定を **Tabs only** に変更します。(既にtabを使う設定になっている場合、一旦spaceにして保存、再度tabに変更して保存します)
その後、保存を行い Preferences ダイアログを閉じます。

[image: Java > Code Style > Formatter]

再度 Preferences を開き **Java > Editor > Typing** を開くと、tabを使ってインデントする、というような説明に変わっていると思います。

[image: uses tab]

Comment: ありがとうございます。確認してみます

Comment: 確認しましたが、タブモードを使用するになっているようです。画像は投稿に追記しました。

Comment: "既にtabを使う設定になっている場合、一旦spaceにして保存、再度tabに変更して保存します" という点については試されたでしょうか。設定を色々触ってみた感じ、表示と実際の挙動が一致しないような状態になることもあるように感じました。

Comment: はい、試してみたのですが、やはりうまくいきませんでした。

Comment: 質問文のキャプチャを見直してみましたが、"Enter key adjusts the indentation on the new line"に相当する設定が無さそうですね。質問文中にEclipseのバージョンも明記したほうが良さそうだと感じました。(少し検索した感じ、過去のバージョンではsmart insert mode的な設定がありそうですが、どうでしょう)

Comment: (回答とは直接関係ありませんが、参考情報として)該当設定の設定ファイル上の項目名は `/instance/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/smartIndentAfterNewline` のようです。

Comment: 今度から明記するように致します。ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます